# Delete white space in GridbagLayout

Tags: java, padding, gridbaglayout

I'm using JsplitPane. I'm using Netbeans gui designer tool.
 i have put in it two JPanels one whom contains three JPanels, i got a white space, with setting

her is an image illustrates what i want to do:

[image: Gridbage layout]
<sub>(source: [gulfup.com](http://im62.gulfup.com/WA1gBY.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), especially the section on using the `weightx/weighty` constraints for the solution to your problem.